# Code behaves different in IDLE and in py script - ghost.py

Tags: python, python-idle, ghost.py

```
from ghost import Ghost
```

running it from IDLE works; but if I run a py file with only this line of code it get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Teo1\Desktop\sub\ghost.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ghost import Ghost
  File "C:\Users\Teo1\Desktop\sub\ghost.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ghost import Ghost
ImportError: cannot import name Ghost
```

It may seem a stupid question, but what it's so simple that I can't find my error.

I'm using ghost.py with PySide, both installed with pip.

Comment: Change the name of your script. Having a script with the same name as a module you are trying to import doesn't going to work.

Comment: thanks. [facepalm] I'm going to downvote my own question

Comment: @DeepSpace Post your answer as an answer so the OP can accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is trying to import itself, since the first module `ghost` it finds is your `ghost.py`.

Renaming your program will fix this problem.